# python how to run loop and append item in list until match with len of old list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new in python.
I have a list like this:

```
new_list = []
list1 = ['a','b','c']
```

I want to run loop and append item in my new_list by matching `len` of list1.
so my expected result will be somethings like this:

```
new_list = [1,2,3]
```

if my `list1 = ['a','b']` then `new_list = [1,2]`

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please give it a try by writing some Python code, and feel free to share that code here if you run into problem, so people can help you with the specific issue. SO is here to help you solve problems like that, no matter how simple or complicated, but it's not here to write your code for you. Have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're unsure what's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) and casting to a `list`:

```py
>>> list1 = ['a','b','c']
>>> new_list = list(range(1, len(list1)+1))
>>> new_list
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

thats how you can do it.

```
for x in range(1,len(list1)+1):
    new_list.append(x)
    
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's **list comprehension**, you are able to do this with 2 lines of code.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
new_list = [i for i in range(1, len(list1)+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `enumerate`:

```py
list1 = ['a','b','c']
output = [i for i, _ in enumerate(list1, start=1)]
print(output) # [1, 2, 3]
```